# SAS how to use a macro variable as a date

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have a global macro variable from another macro which looks like
'01jan2014' when you print it in the log
i.e. there are enforced quotemarks

I want to use this in a proc sql statement but I can't as it doesn't like the variable type.

How do I convert this into a date in the WHERE clause of my proc sql statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To convert a date string in DDMONYYYY format, simple add a `d` to the end.

```
'01jan2014'd
```

will convert the string to a date.

In your case:

```
&var.d
```

will resolve to

```
'01jan2014'd
```

which will be interpreted as a date.

Answer (score 7):

```
%let yourdate = 01Feb2015;
%put &yourdate; /* resolve to 01Feb2015 */

proc sql;
select *
from have
where date ge "&yourdate."d;
```

or

```
%let yourdate2 = '01Feb2015'd;

proc sql;
select *
from have 
where date ge &yourdate2;
```

I think the first one is better since it won't contain `'` in macro variable.

Comment: by default it spits out the date with ' ' wrapped around with it without the date format. this is something in my program that can't be changed